# InnoDB vs MyIsam on a frequently sorted MySQL 5.5 table

Tags: mysql, sorting, innodb, myisam

I have a table (currently InnoDB) with roughly 100k records. These records have an order column so they can make up an ordered queue. Actually, these records belong to about 40 departments that have their own queue which in turn have their own records in this table.

The problem is that we're constantly getting "lock wait time" errors because various departments are sorting its queue (and records) simultaneously.

I know that MyIsam is a `table-level` lock engine and InnoDB is `row-level`. The thing is I'm not sure which one is faster for this kind of operation.

The other thing is that this table is joined in various queries with other InnoDB tables and I don't know the what can happen if I switch the table to MyIsam.

Here's the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `ssti` (
    `demand_nber` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT,
    `year` CHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT,
    `department` CHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '4 caracteres',
    -- [other columns ]
    `priority` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999999',
    PRIMARY KEY (`NR_DMD`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And here's the piece of java code that updates the priorities:

```
PreparedStatement psUpdatePriority = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE `ssti` SET `priority` = ? WHERE demand_nber=?;");

for (int i = 0; i < demands.length(); ++i) {                
    JSONObject d = demands.getJSONObject(i);                

    psUpdatePriority.setInt(1, d.getInt("newPriority"));
    psUpdatePriority.setInt(2, d.getInt("demandNumber"));
    psUpdatePriority.addBatch();                
}

int[] totalUpdated = psUpdatePriority.executeBatch();
```

Comment: Do I understand your problem correctly: may departments sort same table by different columns and get long wait times because of other department locking the table? Please provide sample table structure.

Comment: @Stoleg Various departments sort the same table using the same column [priority]. One more thing to note is that one department can not see the records of another deparment.

Comment: (Minor aside: the `code formatting` backticks are just for code and i/o. They look good, but aren't appropriate for general technical terms, and will generally be edited out as time goes on).

Comment: It sounds like you need to do some research on "lock wait time" errors - maybe your database server needs more memory, or some tuning? What sort of MySQL host are you on - do you have your own VPS/cloud server?

Comment: Would you add into your question an example of the query in which these "various departments" are sorting their queues? Have you got the `EXPLAIN` plan for this?

Comment: @halfer edited to include the Java Code that updates the table.

Comment: Using MyISAM for your primary data storage is usually **totally insane**.

Comment: I can't see any sorting there - did you mean `ORDER BY` in a `SELECT` statement? If so, please add that in.

Comment: "I'm not sure which one is faster for this kind of operation" - why not try both on a dev copy of your data?

Answer (score 0):

When investigating performance problems be sure to engage the [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/slow-query-log.html) so you have a record of the specific queries causing problems.

What it looks like here is you're including a column in your `WHERE` clause that's not indexed. That's extremely painful on large data sets as it requires a "table scan", or reading every record and evaluating them sequentially.

When indexed your queries should be significantly faster.

If you're really up against the wall, you may want to break out each department into their own table. This is very difficult to undo so I'd only pursue this as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Select statements normally do not block each other. Sorting is done in tempDB for each query separately. If you are getting waits for locks, then look at updates that are blocking selects.

With row-locking `UPDATE` will block only needed (small number of) rows, allowing other statements access other rows. With table-locking an `UPDATE` will block whole table and no other statements will access table until `UPDATE` is finished. So MyISAM will make your problem worse in any case.

--

It seems that you are using this table for many purposes. Therefore, you need to consider all of them and their importance, when tuning performance of this table.

**Case 1: Department queries its own data and needs it sorted**

When a result of some data manipulation is reused many times, the general rule is to save it. It would allow reading the result straight away, rather then computing it every time.
To allow queries to read sorted data you need to create an index.

However index just on sorting column `priority` will not help. As each department can see only its own data, every query also contains department number. Hence your index should contain two key columns as `KEY (department, priority)`.

**Case 2: Table is joined to several other tables**

To speed up queries with `JOIN`s you'll need indexes with key same as columns used for joins.

**Case 3: Inserting new, possibly transactional, data**

A single table is limited in how long it can handle inserts of new data and processing reporting queries. Usually, transactional and reporting uses are considered alternative to each other. It is a good practice to use reporting tables, that summarise data from transactional tables. Also joins to dimensions are easier when data is aggregated (there are less rows).